# Exposure to Atmospheric Ammonia. How to not die

Tags: science-based, biology, atmosphere

A follow up to the previous [post](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/214636/breathing-on-high-oxygen-world-what-can-be-done-to-stop-humans-from-dying) question, one of the point's raised in the question was that the  atmosphere that is presented has around 0.7% of it's atmosphere made up of Ammonia which is replenished through biological means.

In said post, a group of humans has been transported to a habitable super earth unspecified means and is stuck there.  Fortunately, said transportation through unspecified means has also modified the humans to be able to breath in said atmosphere.

So:

**Are there any possible physiological changes to the human body that can be done in order for humans to survive in this amount of atmospheric ammonia?**

Comment: That's about 20 times the NIOSH IDLH (Immediately Dangerous to Life and Health) limit, where a 30 minute exposure causes death or permanent health effects. It's likely the required changes would be quite extensive and invasive.

Answer (score 7):

**Glutamine synthetase and lots of it.**

[image: ammonia cycle]

http://education.med.nyu.edu/mbm/aminoAcids/ureaCycle.shtml

Emphasis mine.  In your cells, ammonia (NH4 in the body) is detoxified by adding it to the amino acid glutamate to make glutamine.  Glutamine is useful for all kinds of other things like making other amino acids.  Mostly this happens in the liver.

In your engineered folks it also happens in the lungs.  Huge amounts of glutamate and glutamine synthetase are in the alveolar spaces and when ammonia is absorbed it is grabbed and added to glutamine, fast.  The added protein (as ammonia) can be used to make more glutamate later.

Ultimately this nitrogen excess can be handled by the liver and kidney.  For your engineered folks it is the functional equivalent of eating a very high protein diet.

Comment: “Very high protein diet” may be hard on the kidneys and consequently necessitate supplemental modifications to mitigate.

Comment: @SillybutTrue - Good point.  These people would need to drink immense amounts of beer to dilute out the nitrogen and keep kidneys happy.

Comment: @Willk _that_ may explain the 1.2% CO2 in the atmosphere, lotsa fermentation in those breweries. On the other side, that planet smells of stale piss, I'd try to get out asap.

Comment: I’ll be sure to add germans into the mix of humans.

Comment: Give a thought to the poor people's eyeballs, too. A permanently water-wet surface like the eye will suck up ammonia quite eagerly, and that stuff will burn the <censored comments, more censored comments> out of your poor eyes.

Comment: @PCMan - hm, yes.  They cry all all the time.  Pretty much constantly, about everything.  They are engineered to be extremely sentimental.

Answer (score 6):

Atmospheric ammonia is gonna be a less of a problem. **It is the ammonia dissolved in available water that raises question on the ability to survive a planet with 0.7% atmospheric ammonia**

<strike>[less relevant consideration deleted]</strike>

The planet is defined as habitable, so the planet does have water. Ammonia is 31% soluble in water weight by weight at 20C (increases as the temperature decrease) and 1atm - at 1.5 atm, it will be more.

To have that amount of *free* ammonia in air would mean the surface water of the planet is close to saturation. 25% w/w is way of a conservative figure.
**A quarter of the planet's surface water *by weight* is ammonia?** This spells a way much bigger trouble for human presence than the atmospheric ammonia.

At this ammonia concentration, **the pH of water on the planet will be between 11 and 12**. Not as corrosive as caustic soda, but an Earthling body  left in water will probably dissolve in about a week (except the bones)

The first pure water rain (like we have on Earth) will clear the air in the area where if falls to a 0% ammonia concentration**. The only way to make it rise again is to have the place where the rain falls more alkaline than pH 12. Which you'll get only by [dissolving alkaly or earth-alkaly metal hydroxides](https://www.aqion.de/site/ph-of-common-acids#bases)

As a Lewis base, the ammonium ion is a pretty good complexing agent too. Many transitional (read heavy-) metals, usually insoluble in water, will now be [present in higher concentration in planet's "water"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metal_ammine_complex): copper, nickel, zinc, cobalt, chromium, silver, gold and the entire platinum group. Which means that any existing life on the planet will have a biochemistry alien to humans or Earth. As some examples:

- silver and copper ions - germicidal for Earth microbes. Meaning any life there must've started and continued on totally different evolutionary paths

  if you have copper on the planet, say goodbye to cellulose - it dissolves in almost all tertaaminocopper solutions (I've done it myself starting from copper carbonate + ammonia solution - [Schweizer's reagent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schweizer%27s_reagent) is more effective). The native grasses and trees in there must use another biopolymer for their structure

The tidal pools that started the life evolution on that planet may have show quite interesting colors due to copper and chromium salts.

Even if there's no life on that planet, it means the conditions there are improper to terrestrial life and agriculture. While staying indoor can keep the atmospheric ammonia within safe levels, **there's a snowflake chance in hell a Terran agriculture can be practiced on that planet - what food reserves they have available**?

Otherwise, maybe "said transportation through unspecified means has also modified the humans" so that they are adapted to a diet rich in heavy metals. Probably switched their blood oxygen transport from hemoglobin to hemocyanin.

---

** [First detection of ammonia (NH3) in the Asian summer monsoon upper troposphere](https://acp.copernicus.org/articles/16/14357/2016/)

> Three-monthly, 10° longitude  ×  10° latitude average profiles reaching maximum mixing ratios of around 30 pptv `[parts per trillion in volume]` in this altitude range have been retrieved... On a global scale, outside the monsoon area and during different seasons, we could not detect enhanced values of NH3 above the actual detection limit of about 3–5 pptv.  This upper bound helps to constrain global model simulations.

---

<strike>Once produced it will quickly raise in the upper side of the atmosphere.</strike> (further research confirm
@LoganR.Kearsley note, the gases tend to be well mixed in troposphere. [Example for methane - lighter than air - in Earth's atmosphere](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.3402/tellusa.v18i2-3.9677))

Comment: No, it will not quickly rise to the top of the atmosphere. Below the tropopause, gasses remain well-mixed. If particular locations generate more ammonia than others, air masses will generally rise there, just as moist air rises on Earth, but weather will spread it out before it can stratify.

Comment: @LoganR.Kearsley - point. Will correct.

Comment: Wouldn’t the high CO2 level neutralize the ammonia though?

Comment: @Seraphim Ammonium carbonate [decomposes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ammonium_carbonate) at quite low temperatures. Besides, if the ammonia in the water is bound in salts, why isn't the atmospheric ammonia dissolving in surface water immediately? Ammonia is quite "voracious" for water - [ammonia fountain](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NO7V6TMQuBs)

Comment: Hmm, so either I really need to dial back the ammonia or perhaps have it be consumed by microbial life?  Would add a neat energy cycle i on the planet combined with the ammonia producers.

Comment: @Seraphim Terran life is incompatible with significant atmospheric ammonia concentration - it will eat it as fast as possible. You may get it in isolated places (e.g. intensive pork farms), but not as anything significant as percentage of atmosphere.

Comment: @Seraphim found an article that allows you a concentration of 30e-9 per volume, from time to time. Otherwise it looks like you'll have to dial atmospheric ammonia back to under 5e-9 parts per volume.

Comment: Well, this was my first foray into crafting an atmosphere.  Just thought the ammonia would make it easier for animals to have metals within there metabolisms and as a fertilizer for aerobic plankton.

Comment: @Seraphim [Phytomining](https://grist.org/science/phytomining-nickel-kinabalu-park-malaysia/) "around 700 are so-called “hyperaccumulators,” like Kinabalu’s P. rufuschaneyi. Over time, they suck the soil dry of metals like nickel, zinc, cobalt, and even gold." Greater amount of sulfur oxides get more sulfate salts - the large majority of them [are soluble](https://www.chem.tamu.edu/rgroup/hughbanks/courses/462/handouts/The_Solubility_Rules.pdf).

Comment: @Seraphim  Iron sulfate has been used in [iron fertilisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_fertilization) (instead of nitrogen fertilization), it works only in iron deficient waters. But it shows that it's not necessary nitrogen scarcity that is the most restrictive factor in plankton growth.